# Why Zerobranestudio Configuration error occurs?

Tags: lua, zerobrane

Error while loading configuration file: 'cannot open C:\Users\안진형\Desktop\ZeroBraneStudio.zbstudio\user.lua: Invalid argument'.

Error while loading configuration file: cannot open C:\Users\안진형\Desktop\ZEROBR~1\cfg\tomorrow.lua: Invalid argument

What is "ZEROBR~1" in directory? and Why this message occurs?
I'm setting this program for code debugging and changeing color scheme of zerobranestudio, but I don't know how to open code file and how to change color scheme.

I've tried to do this and succeed to open tommorow.lua. Then Why this error message occurs?
How can i change color scheme?

http://bitstopixels.blogspot.com/2016/09/changing-color-theme-in-zerobrane-studio.html

I've tried this manual and succeed to open scheme-picker.lua. In that link's statement, If i choose color like "Tommorownightblue", Zerobranestudio's color changed to that color. But when i clicked "TommorownightBlue", Error while loading configuration file: cannot open C:\Users\안진형\Desktop\ZEROBR~1\cfg\tomorrow.lua: Invalid argument message occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I'd try loading the configuration files from a different location. Can you move ZeroBrane Studio installation to a location that doesn't have your username in it, as I suspect it may be some encoding issue, which doesn't allow the file name to be properly passed to the `open` function.